# 500 Error for page that is exact duplicate but different name

Tags: dreamweaver

I have duplicated a page in Dreamweaver on the server it has the same content as another page the only difference is the filename.

The original file is working fine but the duplicate is giving a 500 error.

What would cause this and how can I solve it?

I'm thinking it may be the way that the FTP within Dreamweaver is interacting with the server?

**Example:**

Working page - http://www.fibrefab.com/quotation.php

Duplicate page - http://www.fibrefab.com/quotation-Copy.php

Comment: Unsurprisingly there is nothing obvious in what we can publicly see in those pages. You'll have to change the error handling of PHP, or whatever is hiding the details of the 500 error.

Comment: Note that the page is "present", where as some other page, like http://www.fibrefab.com/Quotation.php just throws 404 not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the duplicate page had no permissions set as default!

Problem solved...